# В чем ошибка post запроса?

Tags: python, requests

Пишу парсер для Леруа мерлен. Нашел POST запрос, который подгружает все товары. При попытке запроса выдается данная ошибка:

`{"statusCode":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"body.familyIds should be array"}`

Мок код выглядит следующим образом:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.leroymerlin.ru/hybrid/v1/getProducts"
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Cookie": "disp_react_aa=1; ggr-widget-test=0; _ym_uid=1673878613555346166; _ym_d=1673878613; _ym_isad=1; _gid=GA1.2.1161646569.1673878627; tmr_lvid=a849d94ae31c4eabd3e01a03850170a6; tmr_lvidTS=1673878627967; aplaut_distinct_id=aqbiyiorbrCA; cookie_accepted=true; _gaexp=GAX1.2.GZ3bpEk7SZWRKA8-8Sbb2Q.19410.1; _pickupMapSearch=true; uxs_uid=7e8911f0-95a8-11ed-9c1a-a1cdd468fed2; iap.uid=ec43e4c4ca14446d85897dca1923527b; sawOPH=true; _regionID=34; qrator_jsid=1673944281.670.cLVU9i8tBaqzy0Pt-cgm21egci4kreav4jsojo32860tvs2ms; qrator_ssid=1673944284.389.lw88D0XYcWokcwUX-gmpun66v8avn6hme8ia3cfc0jetphj07; GACookieStorage=GA1.2.2061129031.1673878625; _ga=GA1.2.2061129031.1673878625; _dc_gtm_UA-20946020-1=1; _ga_Z72HLV7H6T=GS1.1.1673944296.3.1.1673944585.0.0.0",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 YaBrowser/22.11.5.715 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
    "x-api-key": "Yeg8l3zQDwpVNBDTP3q6jM4lQVLW5TTv",
    }


data = {"familyIds":["e89ccb60-4671-11ea-b9e6-8d2ee1855ff8"],"limit":30,"regionId":"34","facets":[],"offset":0,"customerId":"GA1.2.1723703033.1674049413","parentFamilyId":"null","searchMethod":"DEFAULT"}

r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

Какие есть идеи решения проблемы?

Comment: в  data ключ "parentFamilyId": "null", заменить на "parentFamilyId": None, а можно просто удалить.

Comment: Убрал все таже ошибка, которая говорит параметр должен быть массивом хотя я его так и передаю.

Comment: массивом в  json json=data в параметрах  requests.post))

Comment: `r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)`

Comment: И получайте данные не через `r.text` а через `r.json()` тогда получите сразу словарь в переменную